# logic converting statements

Tags: logic

> If $p \space \land \space q \implies r$ then what is $\neg r \space \land \space \neg p$?

We want not $r$ and not $p$

This was the example from where I deduced this:

> If the train arrives late and there are no taxis at the station, then
> John is late for his meeting.

But...

> John is not late for his meeting.
>
> The train did arrive late.

So replacing these with symbols $p, q, r$ I deduced the statement at the top.

How can deduce

$q$ from $p \land q \implies r$?

How does addition/substraction, multiplication work in logic?

Comment: easiest to build a truth table

Answer (score 1):

I should start with identifying $p, q, r$.

Let $p$:= the train arrives late.

$q$:= there are no taxis available

$r$:= John arrives late for his meeting. That gives us, in logic:

$$(p \space \land \space q \implies r)\tag{1}$$

$$$$

We are then told that John is not late for his meeting, so we know $\lnot r\tag{2}$ is true.

And we are also told that the train was indeed late, so it is true that  $p\tag{3}$

Then using the contrapositive of $(1)$ (equivalent to $(1)$), we can work we have:

$$\lnot r \rightarrow \lnot(p \land q) \equiv (\lnot r \to (\lnot p \lor \lnot q))\tag{4}$$

Now, by (2), we have $\lnot r$, and with $(4)$ (from 2, 4, Modus ponens), we conclude  $$\lnot p \lor \lnot q\tag{5}$$

Again, we are given $\lnot r$ (john was not late to his meeting) which means either the train was **not** late, or it is **not** the case that there were no taxis available.

But in addition to learning $\lnot r$ we learned that $p \equiv \lnot\lnot p$ (that the train was, in fact was late).

Hence we are left to conclude, given $\lnot(\lnot p)$,  that we therefore have $\lnot q$ (there were in fact taxis available) for the implication (4) as a whole, to be true.  That is, we have $\lnot r \to \lnot q$

---

When you ask: What is $\lnot r\land \lnot p$?  That would mean John was not late, and the train actually  arrived on time.

However, if you want to express

> "John is not late for his meeting.
>
> The train did arrive late.

That would be $\lnot r \land p$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the symbol $\neg$ has the highest precedence.

The implication $a \implies b$ is logically equivalent to $(\neg a) \vee b$.  Using this with your implication, we get
$$
\neg (p \wedge q) \vee r
$$
Applying DeMorgan's law, we have
$$
\neg p \vee \neg q \vee r,
$$
which is still logically equivalent to your original implication.

If we want to study the truth value of $q$, negate the whole thing and use DeMorgan's laws and bring $q$ all the way to the left:
$$
q \wedge p \wedge \neg r.
$$
Thus, if the whole latter expression is true, then $q$ and $p$ must be true, and $r$ must be false.

Comment: When you go from $\neg p \vee \neg q \vee r$ to $q \wedge p \wedge \neg r$ you are negating the entire statement. So for the whole thing to be *false*, $q$ and $p$ must be true and $r$ must be false.

Comment: @kccu, thanks.  I edited to clarify what I meant.